# How can I configure PostgreSQL 9.0 to start automatically under Windows XP?

Tags: postgresql, windows

Yesterday I installed PostgreSQL 9.0 on Windows XP, and after the installation the DB was running. After booting the system this morning, the data base server did not start automatically.

How do I configure Windows XP to start the postgresql demon after each boot/reboot? (I'm a Unix guy, and guess that's easy for someone knowing Windows.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a couple things to check:

1. I believe the Windows PostgreSQL installer has an option you have to check saying you want to run PostgreSQL as a service.  Make sure you used this option when you did your install.
2. Make sure the service is set to start automatically.

   - `Start->Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Services`
   - Find the service (should be named something like `postgresql-9.0`)
   - Make sure the Startup Type is set to Automatic

Comment: The service was already set to start automatically, but there was a problem with the user (postgresql)/the password, which I solved by setting both to the correct values. Thanks again.