# How can I configure PostgreSQL 9.0 to start automatically under Windows XP, Part II?

Tags: postgresql, windows

Two weeks ago I asked ["How do I configure Windows XP to start the postgresql demon after each boot/reboot?"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/580/how-can-i-configure-postgresql-9-0-to-start-automatically-under-windows-xp), and BenV helped me out with [his answer:](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/580/how-can-i-configure-postgresql-9-0-to-start-automatically-under-windows-xp/583#583)

Make sure the service is set to start automatically.

- `Start->Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Services`
- Find the service (should be named something like `postgresql-9.0`)
- Make sure the Startup Type is set to Automatic

Additionally there was a problem with the password for the user postgres that I had to correct, and everything worked fine - until the 2nd reboot (I installed PostgreSQL on my developer PC, which I switch off every night). I had to correct the password again, and have to redo it ever since after every 2nd reboot.

What can I do?

Comment: So is the problem with the password or the installation/configuration of the service?

Comment: @jcolebrand: The problem is that the service "postgres" is set to automatic, but doesn't start automatically after the 2nd reboot (after the first it does). Logged in as administrator one can start the service only after reinserting the password, which seems to be forgotten by Windows. Where the problem comes from, I have no clue.

Comment: The problem you describe sounds like the SF guys would be better suited to help you. This isn't a db problem, it would seem, but a windows issue.

Answer (score 2):

There's also one more setting to be noted...
On the same window where we set Automatic/Manual start up, there's a "Recovery" tab in which we can force the service to restart when a failure occurs.

But this might not be a good idea to use, especially on development environments, since it may help slip some possible problems past the developer's and/or administrator's eyes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had set the server to automatically restart once if it fails, but this doesn't help. I guess I'll ask the guys at sf eventually.